# How to execute a c# code within an SQL procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I had a project in SSIS that I now want to run just by using T-SQL.
Basically I have a datasource where I download csv files everyday into a directory. I have a full c# code that does exactly that and it runs perfectly when embedded in SSIS. How do I execute that code within my stored procedure?
In case it's important, I use sql server 2017.
Thank you!

Comment: [This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?view=sql-server-2017) might help. Add it as a function.

Comment: Would be also my point. Simply start with the documentation and then ask about the parts you don't understand. A bit more complete is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/ms131094(v=sql.100)

Comment: If it's is SSIS, are you asking how to run that package? Deploy the package, presumably in SSISDB, and then you can use SQL Agent to execute it on a schedule, or you can Execute it directly in SSISDB using T-SQL. I find that the easiest way to get the T-SQL is to try to execute it via SSMS and then use the Script tool, to get the SQL that would be run.

Comment: I think yo are starting the wrong way round. Call your C# code (maybe via Powershell) and get the C# code to call into TSQL

Comment: The easier way is to use sqlcmd.exe (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?force_isolation=true) or a power shell script.  You can create a BAT file which calls sqlcmd.exe and also calls you c# application.

Answer (score 0):

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell 'exe location' will do what you need, it will run a cmd shell command, so you can just point it at the .exe of your c# code

```
DECLARE @Cmd nvarchar(500)
SET @Cmd = '"C:\program.exe"'
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```